# Possible issue with interstitial ad

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I just recently put an interstitial ad in my app for the first time.  Up until now I have only used banner ads.  With Banner ads I get about a 1.5%-2.5% click through ratio.  So far my interstitial has received about 40,000 impressions and 3 clicks.  So I am about a .01% CTR.  Given these figures it seems like I might be doing something wrong.  I see that the ad is being displayed the way that it should on my device both in development and production, I of course do not click it as I have read too many horror stories about getting banned from clicking your own ads.

My code is below. Does it look Like I am doing something wrong?  What could cause such an abysmal CTR?

HomeFragment.java

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getContext());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_main));
    mAdListener = new CustomAdListener();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(mAdListener);
    requestNewInterstitial();

    mPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_INTER_AD_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return mView;
}

   private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
    int openCount = mPreferences.getInt(PREFS_INTER_AD_COUNT, 0);
    openCount++;
    editor.putInt(PREFS_INTER_AD_COUNT, openCount);
    editor.apply();

    int tag = (v.getId() == R.id.calculator_cardview) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

    if ((openCount % 20) == 0 ) {
        mAdListener.updateTagAndId(tag, v.getId());
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    } else {
        loadClickedActivity(tag, v.getId());
    }
}

 private class CustomAdListener extends AdListener {
    int viewTag;
    int viewId;

    void updateTagAndId(int viewTag, int viewId) {
        this.viewId = viewId;
        this.viewTag = viewTag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        loadClickedActivity(viewTag, viewId);
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing how your users use the the app. Maybe they click the button so fast that the ad is not yet loaded? You load the ad in postCreateView. On a slow connection it can take several seconds to load. When the users presses the button fast enough then mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() will be false and you'll have to wait another 20 click.

Post a link to your app, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Would that scenario still register an impression?  Is there a better place to load the ad?

Comment: Don't know really. It should register an request, but an impression I don't know. A good place for ad is hard to say as it really depends on the app. Currently Google wants interstital ads in "natural" break point of applications (like loading new activities or web page on a button click), so we can only advise you when we see you app. In the past it was best (in money terms) to show interstial ads on app start and exit, but now that's banned.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you had requested a link to the app.  Here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit

Comment: Try this. Loading the in on app start and show it when an item from menu drawer is selected. Add a 5 minutes interval between ad shows. When ad was showed request a new on. That's what I'm using in one of my apps and it's making good money for me. Maybe you can find better point insert ads in the future, but for now you can try this to see if interstitial ads are woking for you.